# How to detect when arrow key down is pressed / C# WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, events, datagrid

I'm working with WPF C# app, and I need to implement some action when arrow key down on keyboard is pressed, for example:

```
private void Window_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    // Here I gotta check is that arrow key down which invoked this event.. then call a method
    DoSomething();
}
```

I simply can not figure out in wpf how to detect a arrow key down .. 
Any kind of help would be great!

Thanks !

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `KeyEventArgs` hold information about the pressed key in the `KeyEventArgs.Key` property and so you can check for the down arrow key by checking if `e.Key` is equal to [`Key.Down`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.key(v=vs.110).aspx), which is the enumeration value for the arrow down key.

```
private void Window_OnKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Key == Key.Down) // The Arrow-Down key
    {
        DoSomething();
    }
}
```

Comment: single or doble = ?

Answer (score 0):

```
switch (e.Key)
        {
            case Key.Up:
                break;
            case Key.Down:
                break;
            case Key.Left:
                break;
            case Key.Right:
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
```